# How do I add/change columns in CiviReports?

Tags: civireport

How can I add more fields in columns Tab in Constituent Summary or how can I change the Fields names in columns Tab in Constituent Summary? Also every time that I export my report as a CSV file I get the columns in specific order how can I change the order to the one that I want? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is "You can't unless you're a programmer".  This is a feature that was never added to CiviReport.  However, you have many alternatives.

- You can use profiles to create a [Search View](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Format+Advanced+Search+Result+Columns) and use Advanced Search instead of CiviReport.
- You can see if the [Extended Reports](https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports) extension has a report that matches your needs.
- If the field(s) you want to add are custom fields, you may just need to [set them as searchable](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/2050/12).
- You can hook up a [third-party reporting tool](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/73/how-can-i-make-it-easier-for-users-to-generate-the-reports-they-need/180#180).
- Drupal and Backdrop users can use [CiviCRM Views Integration](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/master/integration/drupal/views/) to get the exact columns/order they want.
- If you ARE a programmer, there are [several](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/12219/adding-a-column-to-the-standard-relationships-report-in-contact-reports) [questions](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/944/12) on Stack Exchange to help you with that, along with the [CiviCRM Report Reference](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/framework/civireport/) in the Developer Guide.

Answer (score 2):

You can add new columns if they are custom fields that you have created.
You just need to ensure that the fields are defined as "Searchable" otherwise the fields won't be available in the columns tab.

To check if your custom fields are "Searchable" :

- menu Administer -> Customize data and screen -> custom fields
- choose the custom fields set -> click on View and Edit Custom Fields
- you should set in the column Searchable? the value Yes (in my screenshot, all fields are not searchable so they won't be available for the reports)

[image]