# How to create a recent new contacts report?

Tags: civireport, reports, dashboard

I'm trying to create a report of recent new contacts, ideally to make it available to our team as a dashboard widget.

I've managed to get a report with the results I want using the `Contact Logging Report (Summary)` template, but the columns in that (Action, Log Type, Altered By) will be fairly meaningless to the team, so I want the same results displayed with useful information each contact: things like Job Title, City, e-mail, phone, etc.

I've found [an old answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20618/how-do-i-add-change-columns-in-civireports) that suggests the ability to add columns to templates doesn't exist in CiviReport. Is this still true? And if so, are there any work arounds or extensions that can achieve the same result? I've checked the Extended Reports extension, and even in there I can't find any templates that include both the contact fields and the logging information needed to get a list of recently added contacts.

I'm flexible as to how recent a list I get, as long as it can be sorted with most recent first. And I'm flexible as to exactly which columns I end up with, as long as they're ones that are meaningful to my users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if there are any extension that you do your job using reports but you certainly achieve this via other methods

1. If you are on Drupal than you can use views to create the list by sorting created date by descending order.
2. You can also use [Data Processor](https://civicrm.org/extensions/data-processor) extension to create dashlet or search report with your own columns and  sort by created date by descending order.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I'm a bit of a novice with Views, and never tried getting it to work with CiviCRM. But I've managed to do exactly what I wanted with Data Processor. Just trying to work out if there's a way to include the do not contact flag on phone numbers/e-mail addresses.